# Sprites SVG with CSS and network usage

Tags: css, svg, firebug, css-sprites

I have an SVG sprite with many images (#img1, #img2...).

**Why my browser download each images individually?**

[image]

As you can see, I tried to load the SVG without id, no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate requests to the same resource can be caused by the browser cache being disabled. To ensure it is enabled, click the little arrow within the *Net* panel tab and uncheck *Disable Browser Cache* from the menu.

[image: Unchecked option *Disable Browser Cache* within Firebug's *Net* panel options menu]